# OpenArena for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've installed OpenArena for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS but it crash on startup.

````
ioq3 1.36+u20191029.dc0c3e7~dfsg-1/Ubuntu linux-x86_64 Nov  2 2019
SSE instruction set enabled
----- FS_Startup -----
We are looking in the current search path:
/home/davide/.openarena/baseoa
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/z_oacmp-volume1-v3.pk3 (370 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088.pk3 (711 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch085.pk3 (559 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-misc.pk3 (229 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak5-TA.pk3 (139 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak4-textures.pk3 (1753 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak2-players.pk3 (669 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak2-players-mature.pk3 (231 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak1-maps.pk3 (100 files)
/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak0.pk3 (1042 files)

----------------------
5803 files in pk3 files
execing default.cfg
couldn't exec q3config.cfg
couldn't exec autoexec.cfg
Hunk_Clear: reset the hunk ok
----- Client Initialization -----
Couldn't read q3history.
----- Initializing Renderer ----
Trying to load "renderer_opengl2_x86_64.so" from "/usr/lib/ioquake3"...
-------------------------------
QKEY found.
----- Client Initialization Complete -----
----- R_Init -----
SDL using driver "x11"
Initializing OpenGL display
Display aspect: 1.779
...setting mode 3: 640 480
Trying to get an OpenGL 3.2 core context
SDL_GL_CreateContext succeeded.
Using 24 color bits, 24 depth, 8 stencil display.
Available modes: '320x180 432x243 480x270 512x288 640x360 720x405 800x450 864x486 960x540 1024x576 1280x720 1366x768 360x202 684x384 680x384 1360x768 640x400 720x450 840x525 960x600 800x512 700x450 320x240 400x300 512x384 576x432 640x480 700x525 800x600 896x672 928x696 960x720 1024x768 640x512'
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
Initializing OpenGL extensions
...GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc not found
...ignoring GL_S3_s3tc
...ignoring GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
...using GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp
...using GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
...using GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
...using GL_ARB_texture_float
...using GL_ARB_depth_clamp
...ignoring GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
...using GLSL version 4.20
...GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info not found
...GL_ATI_meminfo not found
...ignoring GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
...ignoring GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc
...GL_EXT_direct_state_access not found
------- FBO_Init -------
------- GLSL_InitGPUShaders -------
loaded 114 GLSL shaders (48 gen 42 light 24 etc) in  0.06 seconds
------- R_InitVaos -------
Initializing Shaders

GL_VENDOR: Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
GL_VERSION: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
GL_EXTENSIONS: GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_AMD_texture_texture4 GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_direct_state_access GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_gl_spirv GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_indirect_parameters GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_include GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_spirv_extensions GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_EGL_sync GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_demote_to_helper_invocation GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_KHR_robustness GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_OES_EGL_image GL_S3_s3tc 
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 16

PIXELFORMAT: color(24-bits) Z(24-bit) stencil(8-bits)
MODE: 3, 640 x 480 windowed hz:N/A
GAMMA: hardware w/ 1 overbright bits
texturemode: GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST
picmip: 1
texture bits: 0
compiled vertex arrays: disabled
texenv add: enabled
compressed textures: disabled
----- finished R_Init -----
------ Initializing Sound ------
Allocated 96 sources.
OpenAL default capture device is 'Audio interno Stereo analogico'
OpenAL capture device opened.
OpenAL info:
  Vendor:         OpenAL Community
  Version:        1.1 ALSOFT 1.19.1
  Renderer:       OpenAL Soft
  AL Extensions:  AL_EXT_ALAW AL_EXT_BFORMAT AL_EXT_DOUBLE AL_EXT_EXPONENT_DISTANCE AL_EXT_FLOAT32 AL_EXT_IMA4 AL_EXT_LINEAR_DISTANCE AL_EXT_MCFORMATS AL_EXT_MULAW AL_EXT_MULAW_BFORMAT AL_EXT_MULAW_MCFORMATS AL_EXT_OFFSET AL_EXT_source_distance_model AL_EXT_SOURCE_RADIUS AL_EXT_STEREO_ANGLES AL_LOKI_quadriphonic AL_SOFT_block_alignment AL_SOFT_deferred_updates AL_SOFT_direct_channels AL_SOFTX_events AL_SOFTX_filter_gain_ex AL_SOFT_gain_clamp_ex AL_SOFT_loop_points AL_SOFTX_map_buffer AL_SOFT_MSADPCM AL_SOFT_source_latency AL_SOFT_source_length AL_SOFT_source_resampler AL_SOFT_source_spatialize
  ALC Extensions: ALC_ENUMERATE_ALL_EXT ALC_ENUMERATION_EXT ALC_EXT_CAPTURE ALC_EXT_DEDICATED ALC_EXT_disconnect ALC_EXT_EFX ALC_EXT_thread_local_context ALC_SOFT_device_clock ALC_SOFT_HRTF ALC_SOFT_loopback ALC_SOFT_output_limiter ALC_SOFT_pause_device
  Device:         Audio interno Stereo analogico
  Available Devices:
Audio interno Stereo analogico
  Input Device:   Audio interno Stereo analogico
  Available Input Devices:
Audio interno Stereo analogico
Monitor of Audio interno Stereo analogico
Sound initialization successful.
--------------------------------
Loading vm file vm/ui.qvm...
File "vm/ui.qvm" found in "/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088.pk3"
...which has vmMagic VM_MAGIC_USE_NATIVE.
... trying pak6-patch088/ui
Loading DLL file /usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088/uix86_64.so instead.
Loading DLL file: /usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088/uix86_64.so
Sys_LoadGameDll(/usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088/uix86_64.so) failed:
"Failed loading /usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088/uix86_64.so: /usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088/uix86_64.so: undefined symbol: __atan2_finite"
Failed to load DLL /usr/lib/openarena/baseoa/pak6-patch088/uix86_64.so.
----- Client Shutdown (Client fatal crashed: VM_Create on UI failed) -----
RE_Shutdown( 1 )
------- FBO_Shutdown -------
------- R_ShutdownVaos -------
------- GLSL_ShutdownGPUShaders -------
Hunk_Clear: reset the hunk ok
OpenAL capture device closed.
-----------------------
VM_Create on UI failed```
````